# Grails REQUIRES_NEW and "Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions"

Tags: grails, transactions, grails-orm

When using the REQUIRES_NEW annotation to create a new transaction on a service method, a new Hibernate session is started which causes an "Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions" error.  This error only occurs when a domain object which contains a collection is being saved. I'm using Grails 2.3.11.

Domain Object:

```
class MyObject {
    String str
    Integer value = 1
    List container
    static hasMany = [container : MyCollection]
}

class MyCollection {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [obj: MyObject]
}
```

Transactional Service:

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation

@Transactional
class MyService {

    def getMyObjectById(Long id) {
        return MyObject.get(id)
    }

    def proxyStartStateMachine(MyObject obj) {
        doStateMachine(obj)

        if (obj.someInteger < 5) {
            triggerStateMachineReentry(obj)
        } else {
            //obj.attach()
            //obj.refresh()
            obj.discard()
        }
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    def doStateMachine(MyObject obj) {
        updateStr(obj, "test${obj.version}")
    }

    def updateStr(MyObject obj, String str) {
        obj.str = str
        obj.save() // generates Hibernate error "Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions"
    }

    def triggerStateMachineReentry(MyObject obj) {
        obj.value++
        obj.save()

        proxyStartStateMachine(obj)
    }
}
```

Controller entrypoint:

```
class ApiController {
    def myService

    def index() { }

    def stuff(Long id) {
        def obj = myService.getMyObjectById(id)
        myService.proxyStartStateMachine(obj)

        render(status: 200, text: 'OK', contentType: "text/html")
    }
}
```

The expected behavior of this service is to have 5 distinct transactions where MyObject.value is updated from 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4, and 4 to 5.  When the collection MyObject.container is removed from the domain object, it works correctly.

MySQL log:

```
2302 Query  SET autocommit=0
2302 Query  update my_object set version=1, str='test0', value=1 where id=1 and version=0
2302 Query  commit
2302 Query  SET autocommit=1
2302 Query  SET autocommit=0
2302 Query  update my_object set version=2, str='test1', value=2 where id=1 and version=1
2302 Query  commit
2302 Query  SET autocommit=1
2302 Query  SET autocommit=0
2302 Query  update my_object set version=3, str='test2', value=3 where id=1 and version=2
2302 Query  commit
2302 Query  SET autocommit=1
2302 Query  SET autocommit=0
2302 Query  update my_object set version=4, str='test3', value=4 where id=1 and version=3
2302 Query  commit
2302 Query  SET autocommit=1
2302 Query  SET autocommit=0
2302 Query  update my_object set version=5, str='test4', value=5 where id=1 and version=4
2302 Query  commit
2302 Query  SET autocommit=1
```

However, as soon as the collection is added to the domain object, it instead fails in MyService when doing the first save in MyService.updateStr().

I know that this is occurring because of the new transaction, but that is a required piece of functionality here to ensure that changes are committed and will not roll back during each iteration of the state machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution.  Prior to creating the new transaction, the object needs to be removed from the Hibernate session using object.discard().

If anyone else has alternative solutions, feel free to suggest them.